# Sphinx Lexical Error parsing grammar file

Tags: java, speech-recognition, sphinx4, jsapi

I have been making a speech recognition program in Java just to see how it works. It was all working completely fine up until a day ago. I have no idea what happened as I didn't change anything in my code.

As it is coming up with a lexical error I think I only need to paste my grammar file.

controls.gram:

```
#JSGF V1.0;

grammar controls;

public <intro> = "Computer";

public <statement> = <open> | <ignore>;

public <open> = "open" ("chrome" | "word");

public <navigate> = "navigate" "to" (("face" book") | ("stack" "overflow"));

public <ignore> = ("don't" "worry") | ("never" "mind");

public <thanks> = "thanks";
```

Error log:

```
Exception in thread "main" edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 11, column 77.  Encountered: "\r" (13), after : "\"));"
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParserTokenManager.getNextToken(JSGFParserTokenManager.java:1197)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.jj_ntk(JSGFParser.java:1012)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.item(JSGFParser.java:643)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.sequence(JSGFParser.java:568)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.alternatives(JSGFParser.java:484)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.item(JSGFParser.java:676)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.sequence(JSGFParser.java:568)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.alternatives(JSGFParser.java:484)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.item(JSGFParser.java:676)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.sequence(JSGFParser.java:568)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.alternatives(JSGFParser.java:484)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.RuleDeclaration(JSGFParser.java:450)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.GrammarUnit(JSGFParser.java:313)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.newGrammarFromJSGF(JSGFParser.java:128)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser.newGrammarFromJSGF(JSGFParser.java:241)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.JSGFGrammar.loadNamedGrammar(JSGFGrammar.java:697)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.JSGFGrammar.commitChanges(JSGFGrammar.java:613)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.JSGFGrammar.createGrammar(JSGFGrammar.java:300)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.language.grammar.Grammar.allocate(Grammar.java:116)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist.allocate(FlatLinguist.java:300)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.allocate(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:646)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.AbstractDecoder.allocate(AbstractDecoder.java:87)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.allocate(Recognizer.java:168)
at [MY PACKAGE].Utils.<init>(Utils.java:23)
at [MY PACKAGE].Launcher.<clinit>(Launcher.java:8)
```

I have tried removing all Whitespace characters, encoding it in ANSI, UTF (with and without BOM). All of which have been to no avail...

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: you have a quote missing: 
public <navigate> = "navigate" "to" (("face" `"`book") | ("stack" "overflow"));

Comment: BOOYAH! Thanks! :D Blimey I've been racking my brains over this for so long. If you answer this I'll give you some rep.

Comment: The syntax highlight actually gave the answer here... :)

Comment: Yeah I noticed it after coming on here to check the comment :) If only Eclipse had grammar file syntax highlighting...

Comment: You can define your own syntax for highlighting in Notepad++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a missing quote:

public  = "navigate" "to" (("face" `"`book") | ("stack" "overflow"));

That should fix it :-)